Modify max text width of notebook output in VSCode
I would like to make the max width of output from a cell in VSCode larger.
For example, see the image below:

I would like more characters before line breaks, desired behaviour example:
array([[6.76857225e-310, 4.78129931e-310, 1.88750000e+001,2.80022222e+002],
       [0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,0.00000000e+000],
       [1.00000000e+000, 5.62500000e-001, 0.00000000e+000,2.50000000e-001],
       [1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+000,1.00000000e+000]]

The ideal case would be to have the breaks at the commas, but that seems context-sensitive and harder to achieve.
Thanks in advance

Not really a problem of VSCode.
Found this: How to set max output width in numpy? answer by @Frank Herfert
Look outdated, but went to Numpy's docs and the following works:
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=100)

